# hadoop MapReduce job on single node Vs Multi node

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hey I have written my first Java code for map reduce.
I have run it on a single node.

But I'm not sure what changes doest it needs to work with multi nodes
If any , could someone direct me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is to follow [this tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/).

The main points that you should have a look at are:

- `/etc/hosts` file **of each node**, where you add the ip of all the nodes (also make sure you can `ssh` to each node without a password)
- `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/masters` and `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/slaves` files in the master node, where you add the corresponding nodes
- increase the number reduce tasks, in case it is 1 and your algorithm supports that. You can do that in your main method, by calling the `setNumReduceTasks(int n)` method (instructions on setting this can be found [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces)).
- set the replication factor in case it is 1 (the default is 3), to take advantage of data locality (data is copied to more nodes, so some data transfering can be saved).
- set the `*-site.xml` files, as instructed in the provided tutorial.

Of course, you should stop the cluster before changes and restart afterwards.

Comment: then, changing the number of reduce tasks is the only I can think of right now